# How to assign a number to a variable in PHP

Tags: php, variables

I am learning PHP and want to assign a number to my variables for use in math functions.

My current code is:

```
  <?php $size = 12; ?>

  <?php $quantity = 10; ?>

  <?php echo $size * $quantity; ?>
```

How could I change it so that 12 in $size equals a number like 19.50, I am trying to do this as if it was a price calculator.

EDIT: To clarify, I don't want to just change 12 to 19.50, the end result I am trying to get to is the user selects a size of "12" from a HTML dropdown menu, and when the PHP math uses the variable it does not multiply it by 12, but rather by a price of 19.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried: <?php $size = 19.50; ?>

Comment: Do you mean something like `$size = $size * 123;`?

Comment: Your question is very vague. Please be more specific!

Comment: Do you mean `<?php echo $size = $size * $quantity; ?>`?

Comment: If you know how to assign `12` to a variable, then why wouldn't the same thing work when applying `19.5` to a variable?

Comment: That would be like what I have right now, what I want is to eventually add these variables to a dropdown menu that would show 12, but the PHP math would use 19.50.

Comment: @npav42: Update your question, and explain that you want the values to depend on user input...

Comment: Really? how to assign 19.50? Just because it's a different number doesn't make assignments in PHP magically different. That'd be like saying "I can't drive this car! It's red! I only know how to drive blue cars!"

Comment: just create a set of prices for each sizes, after submission, get the proper price according to size then multiply it by the quantity

Comment: As I understand it ... why not just, in the HTML, have `<option value="19.5">12</option>` and define `$size` based on the `_GET` var?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a simple condition using `if/else` structure

```
<?php 

$size = 12;                // dummy

if($size==12)              // You can add conditions for other sizes
{
  $number=19.50; 
}                          

?>
```

If there are too many sizes you can consider using `switch` or a multi dimensional array for this. For example

```
$sizes=array();
$sizes[]=array('size'=>12,'number'=>19.50);
$sizes[]=array('size'=>10,'number'=>17.50);
$sizes[]=array('size'=>8,'number'=>16.50);
```

**Based on your edited description**

You can simply rebuild your select box and you wont have to make those assignments in PHP. Like this

```
<select name="sizes">
 <option value="19.5"> Size 12 </option>
 <option value="17.5"> Size 10 </option>
</select>
```

Comment: ... changing the value of the options ... my thoughts exactly ;)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, as it turns out, you want the user to select *"12"* from a dropdown menu, which would translate to your using `19.5` internally. That, to my eye, is quite deceptive, though, but that's none of my business.
How to do that? That's pretty simple: build a form like this:

```
<form method='POST'>
    <select name='number'>
        <option value='19.5'>12</option>
        <option value='20'>1</option>
        <option value'40'>2</option>
    </select>
    <input type='submit' value='Compute'>
</form>
```

Then, have the form processed by PHP. something like this:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['number']))
    {
        $number = (float) $_POST['number'];
        echo $number*10;
    }
```

I can assure you that, if the user selected 12, the actual *value* that will be sent is a string: `"19.5"`, which I cast to float, and assign to the variable `$number`, I echo the value of this variable, multiplied by 10, giving me the output *"195"*. Easy

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and haha, not trying to be deceptive, they would select a size for example of 12 inches, which would have a price assigned to it of $19.50.

Comment: @npav42: You're right, that wouldn't be deceptive. But have you thought about product groups where the price varies based on the finishing material, like cloth vs leather or something? It would appear you are building a web shop platform of sorts. I'd opt to pass the product id as a value, then have PHP query the product details, and the exact price. If you don't: it's a piece of cake for me to alter the request data and send _"12"_ or even _"1"_ as the value, which you use as price back to the server. Anyway: sending back the product ID is what most webshops do

Comment: Yes I'm trying to make a shop for a website I built (buygeminisignletters.com) that would allow users to purchase plastic letters, with a few different variables that effect the price, such as size and font, and then pass that on to a payment processor (likely Stripe) to accept the card.   Thanks for the help / tips, I'm learning PHP on the fly here so forgive me if I don't understand everything being said, but it makes sense to keep the important code such as price that could be changed away from user input HTML modules.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php $size = 19.50; ?>
```

Works for me ...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $size = 19.50; ?>
```

Is this that you want?

Answer (score 0):

do it the same way you used in assigning 12 to $size:

then try your echo statement again:

this time you should have an answer of 195